# Encoding text and file write read error

Tags: c, if-statement, encryption, file-io

I want to write simple encrypt text system that is read from in.txt then write to out.txt
Encryption type is every ascii plus five if char btw u and z , u=a,v=b,......,z=f where is my problem?
Besides, can we do using modulos operator(%) instead of (char-20) if char btw u and z , u=a,v=b,......,z=f where is my problem?
my code is below thank you all appreciated answers.
text is in in.txt that test abcde

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(){

        char ch;
        int st;

        FILE *fptr_in;
        FILE *fptr_out;

        fptr_in=fopen("in.txt","r");
        fptr_out=fopen("out.txt","w");
        if(fptr_in== NULL || fptr_out==NULL)
                    printf("File cannot be opened\n");
        else{
            st=(fscanf(fptr_in,"%c",&ch));
                while(st==1){
           /* for(st=(fscanf(fptr_in,"%c",&ch));
                st==1;
                st=(fscanf(fptr_in,"%c",&ch)))*/

                        st=(fscanf(fptr_in,"%c",&ch));

            if('a'<=ch && ch<='z'){
                fscanf(fptr_in,"%c",&ch);
            if(ch==' ')
                fprintf(fptr_out, "%c", ' ');
            else if('u'<=ch && ch<='z')
                fprintf(fptr_out, "%c", (char)((int)ch-20));
            else
            fprintf(fptr_out, "%c", (char)((int)ch+5));
            }
    }

}
        fclose(fptr_in);
            fclose(fptr_out);

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: That kind of cipher is called [Caesar cipher](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=caesar+cipher) for which there are already many answers on SO. Also, please check the return value of `fscanf` instead of testing `feof`. [Here's why](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong).

Comment: `if('a'<=ch && ch<='z'){ fscanf(fptr_in,"%c",&ch);` wrong.

Comment: bluepixy why ? thank you m oehm i edited

Answer (score 0):

Some comments on your code:

- It's good that you check the file pointers after calling `fopen`, but you should exit the program if you can't open them. Otherwise, the `while` loop is entered and `fscan` calles on a null pointer. You can use `exit(1)` from `<stdlib.h>`. (This is almost like returning 1 from `main`, but can be called from everywhere.)
- `fscanf(f, "%c", &ch)` is better rendered as `ch = getc(f)`. Likewise `fprintf(f, "%c", ch)` can be written more succinctly as `putc(ch, f)`. (Your variants aren't wrog, but needlessly wordy, in my opinion.)
- Your cipher code has three cases: Space, letters u to z, and everything else. That means that you also shift punctuation and special characters like newline. You should probably use the three cases uppercase letter, lowercase letter and everything else.

Below's a working implementation. Things to note:

- I use `getc`, which requires `ch` to be an int.
- Reading the chars from *in.txt* is done in an infiinite loop with `for(;;)`. The loop ends with the `break` statement when `EOF` is read. (Ii is usually better to have loops with proper conditions, but in this case I prefer the `break`, because it allows me to make `ch` local to this loop and also doesn't need assignments in conditions, which I find ugly.
- The Caesar cipher is implemented as a separate function, to which the shift is passed. It encodes uppercase and lowercase letters by using the modulo function you suggested. This requires a positive shift.
- Note that both the I/O loop and the cipher function are quite short, which is nice.

Here's the example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define INFILE "in.txt"
#define OUTFILE "out.txt"

int caesar(int ch, int shift)
{
    while (shift < 0) shift += 26;
    if ('a' <= ch && ch <= 'z') return ('a' + (ch - 'a' + shift) % 26);
    if ('A' <= ch && ch <= 'Z') return ('A' + (ch - 'A' + shift) % 26);
    return ch;
}

int main()
{
    FILE *fptr_in;
    FILE *fptr_out;

    fptr_in = fopen(INFILE, "r");
    if (fptr_in == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open %s.\n", INFILE);
        exit(1);
    }

    fptr_out = fopen(OUTFILE, "w");
    if (fptr_in == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't create %s.\n", OUTFILE);
        exit(1);
    }

    for (;;) {
        int ch = getc(fptr_in);

        if (ch == EOF) break;
        putc(caesar(ch, 5), fptr_out);
    }

    fclose(fptr_in);
    fclose(fptr_out);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: that's very good :) however i wonder where my wrong is in my code

Comment: also why modulo %26 ?

Comment: @Soner: I've tried to address some "issues" with your code in the answer. I think the main problem is in how you read the data. For example, there should only be one `fscanf` (or `getc`) in the loop, but you have a second one where you read the next character when the current one is a letter, which doesn't make sense. If you want to correct your code, I suggest that you write a program to copy all chars from in.txt to out.txt verbatim. When that works, add the encryption.

Comment: @Soner: Why 26? There are 26 letters in the Latin alphabet. The expression `'a'` gives me the ASCII code of a small a. The expression `ch - 'a'` yields the ordinal number of a letter in the alphabet: 0 for a, 1 for b, 25 for z. Add the (positive) shift. Then calculate the modulo, so that letters that go beyond z are wrapped back to the beginning: z + 5 is 25 + 5 is 30. 30 modulo 26 is 4, which yields an e.